# send angular application logs to elastic search

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, logging, elastic-stack

I am trying to send angular logs(exceptions, errors) to elastic search. so basically we have a planned to create a intermediate logging api that would push the data to elastic search. I have the API written in .net and it can talk to elastic search. but my question is how can I assign properties in the log while I forward them over from angular to api. I don't see much example with that. my question is, Is this approach right (angular logs -> intermediate api -> elastic search) ?
If so, can you please suggest how can I add indexing or timestamp when I send the logs from angular to intermediate api?

Here is the part of the logs directly generated from the api

```
{
  "_index": "logging-api",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "qILeJHcB_U03uXCAT1zW",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2021-01-21T12:14:45.0102735+00:00",
    "level": "Information",
    "messageTemplate": "Executed action {ActionName} in {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms",
    "message": "Executed action \"Logging.API.Controllers.LoggingController.Get (Logging.API)\" in 0.6977ms",
    "fields": {
      "ActionName": "Logging.API.Controllers.LoggingController.Get (Logging.API)",
      "ElapsedMilliseconds": 0.6977,
      "EventId": {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "ActionExecuted"
      },
```

Comment: What kind of application logs you mean ? Do you want to capture errors and exceptions which was thrown in browser console ?

Comment: yes, currently I have a centralized logging service it just logs in console and consume the exception. I want to post the error along with any useful information to the server